# Black box instead of the image in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, canvas, html2canvas

maybe someone can help me with saving pdf file with images on it by using html2canvas
this is my code

```
 html2canvas(document.images, {
        onrendered: function(canvas){

            let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            ctx.globalAlpha = 0.05;
            ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";

            let img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
            let doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
            doc.save('Wishes.pdf')
        },
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe because you draw the image before it's loaded

I have found this exemple : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24997626/9231356

Hope it will work for you!